# Network error: Converting circular structure to JSON on refetch

Tags: react-apollo, apollostack

This is quite a weird problem.

I have a fairly simple query, which runs perfectly well in Graphiql no matter how many times I trigger it

But in browsers the problem appears when I call `data.refetch()`. Most strange that in Chromium I get 
`Network error: Converting circular structure to JSON`
when if FF the error is
`Network error: cyclic object value`

In Chrome, where I don't have redux-dev-tools installed, the error is the same as in Chromium

Other queries refetch nicely, but this one is stuck! Of course I've restarted the server many times, cleared the cache, etc..

I am using apollo v2 and the query is nothing special:

```
query ProductsListQuery($offset: Int!, $limit: Int!) {
  products(offset: $offset, limit: $limit) {
    items {
      id
      title
      shortDescription
      tags
      imagesIds
      __typename
    }
    total
    __typename
  }
}
```

Result:

```
{
  "data": {
    "products": {
      "items": [
        {
          "id": "5a39b5469066625581a326c4",
          "title": "Test1",
          "shortDescription": "",
          "tags": [],
          "imagesIds": {
            "main": null
          },
          "__typename": "Product"
        },
        {
          "id": "5a39b55b9066625581a3270b",
          "title": "Test2",
          "shortDescription": "",
          "tags": [],
          "imagesIds": {
            "main": null
          },
          "__typename": "Product"
        }
      ],
      "total": 2,
      "__typename": "ProductsPaginated"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please post the part of your code where you're actually calling refetch. It sounds like your call to refetch is triggering another refetch call, and so on.

Comment: Thank you mr. Readen, you comment made me look at how refetch is called and I've found a bug (or feature) strange and silly in one, and I've updated the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to @Daniel Rearden I've looked into how the refetch is triggered and found out that this doesn't work for reasons I can't explain:

`<Button onClick={data.refetch} />`

but this works

`<Button onClick={() => data.refetch() />`

Comment: fyi the difference between the two is the value of `this`, which causes the difference here.

Comment: But there's no difference in scope between those two, so it can't be the value of `this`, right?

Comment: the difference is that `refetch` may have some arguments (query variables I think, don't remember now). And the first  call will send `event` as a first refetch argument and everything breaks because of that